# Loop para ggplot2 - plotar 10 cidades por vez

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como consigo criar um loop para imprimir o gráfico abaixo?

Quando quero plotar para os 645 municípios, aí não fica boa a visualização. A ideia é usar o loop para imprimir de 10 em 10 cidades ou talvez individualmente.

A variável drs4 = 9 municípios.

```
drs4 |> 
  group_by(ano, codmunres) |>
  filter(qtdgestant < 1) |> 
  summarise(idade_media = mean(idademae, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = ano, y = idade_media)) +
  geom_line(group = 1) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Idade média de mulheres no parto - primeira gestação",  
       x = "Ano",                 
       y = "Média de idade") +     
  facet_wrap(vars(codmunres), scales = "free_x")
```

Answer (score -2):

Pode criar um ficheiro PDF com 10 gráficos em cada página com o pacote `ggforce`. No exemplo abaixo vou usar a base `diamonds` do pacote `ggplot2` para traçar 3x3 = 9 gráficos por página. Ao todo serão 5 páginas.

## 1. Gráfico inicial

Primeiro carregar os pacotes necessários e criar um objeto `p` com o gráfico inicial. A função `facet_wrap_paginate` do pacote `ggforce` vai paginar os gráficos, 9 em cada página. Mas como um dos argumentos diz qual a página a mostrar, este primeiro objeto só serve para saber quantas páginas são ao todo. Isso é determinado com a função `n__pages` chamada logo a seguir.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

data("diamonds", package = "ggplot2")

p <- ggplot(diamonds) +
  geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
  facet_wrap_paginate(~ cut:clarity, ncol = 3, nrow = 3, page = 1)
np <- n_pages(p)
```

## 2. Gráfico base

Agora vou criar um objeto `"ggplot"` com o gráfico base. É a este objeto que depois vou acrescentar o `facet_wrap_paginate` no ciclo `for`.

```
g <- ggplot(diamonds) +
  geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1)
```

## 3. Criar o PDF

Agora está tudo pronto para criar um PDF com 9 gráficos por página. Isso é feito em ciclo `for`. Veja o argumento `page = i` abaixo.

```
pdf("~/Temp/so_pt_593462.pdf")
for(i in seq.int(np)) {
  p <- g + facet_wrap_paginate(~ cut:clarity, ncol = 3, nrow = 3, page = i)
  print(p)
}
dev.off()
```

Para ter 10 gráficos por página tente, por exemplo, `ncol = 5, nrow = 2`.
Ou para ter 12, `ncol = 4, nrow = 3`.

Comment: Funcionou com alguns ajustes, obrigado pela ajuda.